# What type of insulation has the highest R value per inch?

Tags: insulation, ceiling

I am trying to find the best insulation for my apartment. The limitation is that space between the drywall and the ceiling is 1/2". I live on the top floor of my building.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked, polyisocyanurate has the best insulation value per inch (R-6.5) of all the conventional building insulation products, and it is available in 1/2" sheets.

Comment: Polyiso sounds neat, but it performs worse at low temperatures: _"It's R-6 per inch during the summer, but only R-4.5 per inch on a cold day in winter."_ so it provides somewhere between R36 and R27 in a 6" space. [ https://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/article/cold-weather-performance-of-polyisocyanurate ]

Answer (score 1):

Likely the best insulator that you could use would be a vacuum. You can purchase "vacuum insulating panels", but they will be difficult to install, expensive, and might end up being too thick. The panel would get you to at least R-20, and probably higher. The material that makes the most sense for you to use is polyisocyanurate. At 1/2 in thickness, it will provide approximately R-3.2. Be sure to seal between the boards, as air leaks can cause quite substantial heat loss.

Answer (score 1):

Silica Aerogel products should beat polyisocyanurate;  [10.3 per inch](http://www.thermablok.com/thermal-insulation/residential-construction.htm) in commercially-available products.

[Polyisocyanurate's performance decreases over time](http://www.buildingscience.com/documents/information-sheets/info-502-temperature-dependent-r-value/); The manufacturers and the NCRA factor this into the R-Value of Polyisocyanurate products differently.

Vacuum Insulating Panels can use Aerogels as a filler, so you still get about R9 even if you destroy the vacuum with a nail or screw.

Comment: Also see "Spaceloft" : https://www.aerogel.com/product/spaceloft/